# Reading TEXT type from SAP HANA into python

Tags: python, sql, parsing, hana, stringio

I am working on a project that requires me to get data from a SAP HANA database. I utilized SAP Cloud Connector and PyHDB for the job. I execute my select statement and obtain the result data. One of the fields is a TEXT type, containing large articles. While iterating each row I need to somehow get the data from the TEXT field into a string. However I am only able to get the first 1024 characters. The object that stores the TEXT appears to be a StringIO type. How can I read the entire text data instead of the first 1024 characters only?

```
import pyhdb

connection_from = pyhdb.connect(
host="localhost",
port=00000,
user="user",
password="password"
)
cursor_from = connection_from.cursor()

cursor_from.execute('SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE')
results= cursor_from.fetchall()

for row in results:
    text = row[2].data.getvalue()

connection_from.close()
```

This is the what the object looks like: [NClob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc2y2.png)

I need to get the whole text into a string then print it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the data here or into a gist instead? https://gist.github.com/ I can't access imgur for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhdb/0.2.3#lobs), you need to call `.read()` on the returned object, passing in the number of bytes you want to get. This is not a very friendly interface, but I guess if you pass in a number that is definitely bigger than all your objects, you'll get everything. Or you could do a small loop that iterates with bigger values until you have it all - when the length of string returned by `.getvalue()` does increase.